# Flutter- .dart_tool and build file are red

Tags: flutter

I am new in android studio and i dont know is it normal. flutter and dart plugins installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajlKs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbtLg.png)

.dart_tool and build are red I haven't done anything on the file I opened yet.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and for some reason, my build will not complete with error [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Invalid apk]. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you run the project, those red folders will be created automatically. There is no problem, continue to coding...